# html 5 data-* syntax cannot bind value in angular 2?

Tags: html, angular

I have an object array like this

```
Heros=[{
  heroName:"card1",
  heroType:"type1",
  heroHtml:"<p>card 1</p>"
}, 
{
  heroName:"card2",
  heroType:"type2",
  heroHtml:"<p>card 2</p>"
}
]
```

and I want to display it in my html page use like this

```
<div *ng-for="#hero of heros" data-hero-type="hero.heroType" [inner-html]="hero.heroHtml"></div>
```

can see a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DPOeTpaYsOlWIPos4xoU?p=preview) here.

why the data-component-type cannot get right value? If this is forbidden or not recommanded, what else solution can be used to bind value to html 5 custom attribute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `data-hero-type` is not a div's property, but an attribute, so to make it work you have to use

```js
[attr.data-hero-type]="hero.heroType"
```

See this issue for reference [#5014](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5014)

And you are good to go ;)